# Kernel of cononical ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

My question is what exactly does the kernel of a map $\phi:R\to R/S$ look like? By definition my first guess it write $\mathrm{ker}\phi=\{a:\phi(a)=0\in R/S\}$ but the "zero element" in $R/S$ is just $S$. So is the correct set builder notation $\{a:\phi(a)\in S\}$ or $\{a:\phi(a)=S\}$? The latter seems to be incorrect just by looking at it but I wanted a second opinion. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter is correct, and the first one is not correct. Formally, $R/S$ is a set of equivalent class of $R$ given by an ideal $S$. That is,
$$R/S=\{x+S:x\in R\}$$
where $x+S=\{x+s:s\in S\}$. Since $S$ is an ideal, $R/S$ has a naturally defined addition and multiplication namely
$$(a+S)+(b+S)=(a+b)+S\qquad\text{and}\qquad (a+S)(b+S)=ab+S.$$
In 'quotient ring' $R/S$, additive identity is $0+S$, and it is just equal to $S$.

---

However, in many cases, we represent the elements (of the form $a+R$) of quotient rings by "choosed" element in that equivalent relation. For example, in the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}/54\Bbb{Z}$, we does not represent the elements of the ring of the form $a+54\Bbb{Z}$ in many cases. Instead, we just use the representative of an equivalent class like $39$ or $93$ instead of $39+54\Bbb{Z}$.
I think these convention makes confusion.

Comment: This helps clear things up. Thank you!